# alert JavaScript vs otros

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

sucede que tengo actualmente alertas con [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started) misma que funciona perfecto.

**La cuestión:**

es mejor manejar este tipo de alertas con JS puro(VanillaJS) u otras librerias hablando de rendimientos?

Esta pregunta nace dado que existen sitios donde manejan demasiada información y siempre usan las alertas típicas de **JS**  como es el caso de este sito **S.O.**

Ejemplo de las dos alertas:

```js
function alertaJs(){
alert('Alerta con JavaScript');
}

function alertaSweet(){
swal('Alerta con SweetAlert Js');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alertaJs();">Alerta JavaScript</button><br>
<button onclick="alertaSweet();">Alerta SweetAlert</button><br>
```

Muy independiente de lo "bonito" que se pueda ver las alertas debe existir una razón lógica para usar o no estas librerías, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por experiencia no encuentro una razón técnica que indique no usar métodos alternativos.

Ahora sí quieres utilizar la alerta standard debes tener muy en cuenta que esta detiene el hilo de ejecución y si ese no es tu propósito es mejor usar console.log.

Por otro lado, si lo que pretendes es detener la ejecución por depuración u otro motivo no hay nada de malo en usar una alert o siempre que la pausa de ejecución no afecte tu código.

Te paso un ejemplo donde puedes ver como el alert detiene la ejecución y por otro lado la librería que has presentado no (el tiempo que se ve es solo lo que demora en procesar la tarea mas no detiene la ejecucion ya que el console.log sale igual aunque no cierre el mensaje).

```js
function alertaJS(){
    var tiempo1 = performance.now();
    alert('Mensaje de alerta');
    var tiempo2 = performance.now();
    console.log("El tiempo de demora fue " + (tiempo2 - tiempo1) + " milisegundos.");

};

function alertaS(){
    var tiempo1 = performance.now();
    swal('Mensaje de alerta');
    var tiempo2 = performance.now();
    console.log("El tiempo de demora fue " + (tiempo2 - tiempo1) + " milisegundos.");

};
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="alertaJS();">Alerta JavaScript</button><br>
<button onclick="alertaS();">Alerta SweetAlert</button><br>
```

Comment: Saludos y gracias por tu respuesta en efecto es cierto lo que detiene el hilo de ejecución el alert de Js  pero mas el análisis esta enfocado las alertas para el usuario como tipo "Datos grabados con exito"..'Campo faltante'...etc... en ese tipo de alertas hace referencia la pregunta.

Comment: @DiegoAvila según entendí consultabas si hay diferencias de rendimiento al manejar los alert y como tal no existen salvo que utilices un alert muy complejo o que el mismo distorsione demasiado la lectura de código. Si es que queda mejor a usuarios no entiendi esa referencia. Pero para usuarios no me gusta el alert standard porque algunos ocupan mucho el mouse y deben ir hasta arriba del navegador para darle en aceptar (claro que pueden usar enter pero no todos lo usan o saben).